# How to avoid the nan error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need the height of several containers to be subtracted from a number (for example 1000) at the same time this number must be a css value (in this case 1000px).
But when I add the height of the containers and subtract it from the number 1000 I get the NaN error.
I need an answer without the use of jquery.
This is the code:

```
let carouselHeight = document.getElementById("carouselExampleAutoplaying").offsetHeight;
let cardHeaderHeight = document.getElementById("cardHeaderDiv").offsetHeight;
let navbarHeight = document.getElementById("navDiv").offsetHeight;
let bannerHeight = document.getElementById("topBannerDiv").offsetHeight;
let CardBody = document.getElementById('CardBody');
CardBody.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + 1000 - bannerHeight - navbarHeight - cardHeaderHeight - carouselHeight + 'px');
```

Comment: I think you're mixing arithmetic operations and concatenation operations. Do your arithmetic first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is concatenating strings and trying to perform math on strings:

```
'height: ' + 1000 - bannerHeight - navbarHeight - cardHeaderHeight - carouselHeight + 'px'
```

Specifically, it's first doing `'height: ' + 1000` which results in the string value `'height1000'`, then it's trying to do: `'height1000' - bannerHeight`, the result of which is not a number because you can't subtract from a *string*.

For example:

```js
const bannerHeight = 1;
const navbarHeight = 2;
const cardHeaderHeight = 3;
const carouselHeight = 4;
const result = 'height: ' + 1000 - bannerHeight - navbarHeight - cardHeaderHeight - carouselHeight + 'px';
console.log(result);
```

But you intended this part to be math:

```
1000 - bannerHeight - navbarHeight - cardHeaderHeight - carouselHeight
```

Perform the math first, then use the result in your string.  Which you could do as a separate operation, or by simply wrapping the expression in parentheses to control the order of operations:

```
'height: ' + (1000 - bannerHeight - navbarHeight - cardHeaderHeight - carouselHeight) + 'px'
```

For example:

```js
const bannerHeight = 1;
const navbarHeight = 2;
const cardHeaderHeight = 3;
const carouselHeight = 4;
const result = 'height: ' + (1000 - bannerHeight - navbarHeight - cardHeaderHeight - carouselHeight) + 'px';
console.log(result);
```